# windows 10 default calendar cannot be set to the calendar app

Tags: calendar, windows-10

I'm just playing around with windows 10 and I like the calendar app that is associate with the mail app that comes with windows 10 (it is basically outlook I think). In the default apps section of the settings there is an option for default calendar which is left blank by default and windows cannot find the app named "calendar" to be set as the default calendar, and I cant figure out how to manually set it.

Does anyone have an answer to this?